# Is there a way to append the name of a function to a list automatically?

Tags: python, function, append

The idea is that when a new function is written, it's variable name is appended to a list automatically.

**Just to note, I realise I can just use mylist.append(whatever) but I'm specifically looking for a way to automatically append, rather than manually.**

So, if we start with...

```
def function1(*args):
    print "string"

def function2(*args):
    print "string 2"

mylist = []
```

...is there a way to append 'function1' and 'function2' to mylist automatically so that it would end up like this...

```
mylist = [function1, function2]
```

Specifically, I'd like to have the variable name listed, not a string (e.g. "function1").

I'm learning Python and just experimenting, so this doesn't serve any particular purpose at the moment, I just want to know if it's possible.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and happy answer any questions if I've not been clear.

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the function object to the list:

```
mylist = [function1, function2]
```

or use `.append()`:

```
mylist.append(function1)
mylist.append(function2)
```

Python functions are first-class objects. They are values, just like classes and strings and integers.

If you want to automate this for a whole module, you can use the [`globals()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) to quickly list all functions defined in the module so far, with a little help from the [`inspect.isfunction()` predicate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction):

```
import inspect
mylist = [v for v globals().itervalues() if inspect.isfunction(v) and v.__module__ == __name__]
```

The `v.__module__ == __name__` test ensures we only list functions from the current module, not anything we imported.

However, explicit is still better than implicit. Either add `mylist.append(functionname)` below each function, or use a decorator:

```
mylist = []
def listed(func):
    mylist.append(func)
    return func

@listed
def function1():
    pass

@listed
def function2():
    pass
```

Each function you 'mark' with the `@listed` decorator is added to the `mylist` list.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for the response. I know it's possible to do this, but specifically I wanted to know if it was possible to do it automatically. The thought is that if I were to write many functions, I then wouldn't have to bother adding each one to the list manually.

Comment: @user2061277 Explicit is better than implicit. How would it even determine what to put into this list and what not?

Comment: @user2061277: That was not clear from your question. There are numerous options; using decorators ('marking' all functions that you want to be added to the list with a little extra syntax), listing all objects in the `globals()` namespace then filtering on functions, etc.

Comment: I've amended the question to reflect this. decorators and globals sounds interesting so I'll go away and do some learning. Thanks!

Comment: This solution did exactly what I was hoping. Great lesson.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you could do that with a **decorator**, which would probably qualify as a semi-automatic solution:

```
@gather
def function1():
    print "function 1"

@gather
def function2():
    print "function 2"
```

One implementation of such a decorator is essentially a function which gets a function as a parameter:

```
function_list = []

def gather(func):
    function_list.append(func)  # or .append(func.__name__)
    return func
```

In this simple incarnation it is probably not useful at all, but popular libraries and frameworks often employ a somewhat enhanced version of this technique. As an example, see the Flask's [`@app.route`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.route) decorator for specifying functions that handle specific HTTP requests.